# Install R on rhel 6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, compiling, shared-library, r

Am getting below error when I do `./configure -with-x=no`

```
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

Installation Steps which I follow

```
sudo chown -R root:root R-3.6.1/


sudo yum group install "Development tools"
sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"

sudo yum install readline-devel
sudo yum install xz xz-devel 
sudo yum install pcre pcre-devel
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
sudo yum install texlive
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
sudo yum install *gfortran*
sudo yum install zlib*
sudo yum install bzip2-*


./configure -with-x=no
```

Getting error here

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 2):

You must install `zlib` development package

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```